# Remove all inside square brackets

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

As a title I'm trying to remove all inside square brackets from a string.
If I've for example a string like:

```
"This is a [value1] string within some [image-nnnn] stuff between square  [image] brackets"
```

I would achieve this result:

```
"This is a string within some stuff between square brackets"
```

Could be possible use regex like this to find and remove that stuff?

```
val pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]")
```

Or need I to find and replace manually?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The code above not working because not find any maches when I execute:
patter.matcher("This is a [value1] string within some [image-nnnn] stuff between square  [image] brackets").matches()

Comment: What is not working, can you show full code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is on the right track, but I would use this version:

```java
String input = "This is a [value1] string within some [image-nnnn] stuff between square  [image] brackets";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\s*\\[.*?\\]\\s*", " ").trim();
System.out.println(output);

// This is a string within some stuff between square brackets
```

The regex pattern `\s\[.*?\]\s*` also matches any whitespace on either side of the bracketed term, replacing by a single space.  This correctly splices together the two halves of the sentence.  Then we trim to remove any leading/trailing whitespace.